# CubeField? Setting filter values on pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an excel file with several Macros. In this file there is a pivot table with a column called "Customer", which contains several elements (thousands). What i want to know is, is there any efficient way to set up the filter of this column to specific values?

The reason why i am asking is because the spread sheet will ask the user to select some customers, which are stored in a array, I want to take the values in this array and filter the pivot table accordingly.

I was able to do this by looping the pivot table through all the items, making them `visible = false`, and then making those that were selected, `visible = true`. However, the issue with this approach is that it takes so much time to process.

I have seen some examples in the web of people using the `CubeField` option, however, I am unsure how to use it? The syntax is a bit complex, I have tried the following and it gives me an error:

```
Worksheets("Analysis").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Supplier_Code").ClearAllFilters
Worksheets("Analysis").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Supplier_Code").CubeField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
Set pt = Worksheets("Analysis").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
With PT
    pt.PivotFields("[PivotTable1].[Supplier_Code]").VisibleItemsList = Array("[PivotTable1].[Supplier_Code].&[106214]", "[PivotTable1].[Supplier_Code].&[101160]") ' ===>
```

Here I am not using the array values, just trying to set the customers directly, 1 supplier code is 106214 and the other is 101160.

Any help to get me to the right direction will be highly appreciated. Also, please note that I am not looking to set the filter to 1 item only, I am able to do this already without any issues, the issue here is to select multiple values at once, without looping though all the possible values that could be selected.

Answer (score 1):

When your PivotTable is selected, in the top menu, go to "PivotTable Tools," then "Options", then pick "Insert Slicer" from the Ribbon.  This feature does what you want -- let's you easily select filters (one at a time or multiple), and see the different results of the PivotTable.